# Expected value of multiple choice exercise

Tags: expected-value

I hope this question is not too off-topic but I am wondering why the multiple choice exercise (just "Yes" or "No" answers) in our exam is graded as follows:

*Every correct answer gives $3$ points,
every wrong answers gives $0$ points and
if you don't answer you receive $1.5$ points.*

Have you any idea why someone would use this strange grading scheme? In my opinion this grading scheme would be a strong advantage, in terms of expected value, to students who didn't learn. Or am I missing something?

Why not just give negative points for wrong answers and $0$ points for not answering? This would be less advantageous for students who didn't learn.

Comment: If you give -3 points for the wrong answer, you are in the same situation, up to some scaling. One good and one bad answers are equivalent to two no answers.

Comment: @Andrei and I'm guessing that most computerized gradebooks wouldn't accept negative grades.

Comment: In our other exams there are negative points in multiple choise exercises and if you have a negative amount of points at the end of the multiple choice exercise, those negative points do not reduce the points you receive from other exercises but they just don't count anymore. However, maybe there is no other reason than reducing the emphasis on this multiple choice exercise.